# How to make an text generator

Tags: python

I been stuck in this line of code trying to make a text generator that generates a random text with a vocabulary, like I'm trying to make a code that generates text with the letters ABCDE on uppercase and on lowercase and the numbers 12345, this is my code I been stuck on:

```
import string
import random # define the random module
S = 681  # number of characters in the string
#call random.choices() string module to find the string in Uppercase + numeric data.
ran = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase, k = S))
print("Generated text is : " + str(ran)) # print the random data
```

If you could help I will be extremely thankful (I'm spanish so if I speak bad english thats why)

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I been stuck in this code trying to make a code that generates text with a programated vocabulary.

Comment: Yes, you're stuck, but what does the code do that it shouldn't do? Or what does it not do that it should do?

Comment: What does the code print vs what you expect?

Comment: I can't create the programated vocabulary thats why I am stuck, it should generate text with a programated vocabulary and I can't do it. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Do you want to select random words from a list?

Comment: I want the code to generate text from a list of letters that I programed.

Comment: It generates something. Unclear what else you expect https://www.ideone.com/TeQSJu

Comment: "with the letters ABCDE on uppercase and on lowercase"... If that is exactly what you want, then please explain why you are using `string.digits` or all other letters

Comment: I think you don't understand my idea, I'm trying to make a code that generates text from a list of letters that I created, I don't know how to make the code generates text from a list thats why I am asking for help, the code that I created it generates text but not from a list of letters and I don't know how to make the code do that.

Comment: Look at what you gave to the random function. Your code adds **all** letters (upper and lower case) **and digits**.. If you wanted specific letters, you need to give those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a list of your desired letters there.

```
import string
import random # define the random module
S = 681  # number of characters in the string

letters = 'abcdefg' 

ran = ''.join(random.choices(letters, k = S))
print("Generated text is : " + str(ran)) # print the random data
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you expect to only generate a string with characters that are `[A, B, C, D, E, a, b, c, d, e, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

You can easily use a constrained set of characters to use:

```py
ran = ''.join(random.choices("ABCDEabcde12345", k = S))
```

Output for a k=30:

```
>>> ''.join(random.choices("ABCDEabcde12345", k=30))
'aCdEaaeC5C52eBaD1d1AC543Ace55c'
```